# consult a suggestion about modify docker daemon labels

Tags: docker

We use swarm as orchestration tools. And we add labels on docker daemon to let swarm to do some specific scheduling, such as schedule redis container to the docker daemon which has ssd label.

But in some case, we need to change the docker daemon labels, such as we want add MapR-ability label to some daemon in the midnight, so the map reduce container could be scheduled to this daemon.

There's no API to change the daemon labels on the fly, and we can't afford to restart daemon. So we want add API to do that, such as:

```
Usage: docker labels [COMMAND] [OPTION]

Manage docker daemon labels:

list - show the docker daemon labels.
add - add new labels to docker daemon, docker labels add --label=[k=v]
remove - remove any exist labels from docker daemon, docker labels remove --label=[k]
```

How can I hack docker?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, `docker daemon` has the option `--label=[]                             Set key=value labels to the daemon` already. Refer: https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/daemon/

Comment: @BMW `--label=[]` just Set key=value labels to the daemon, I want to show the docker daemon labels, add new labels to docker daemon and remove any exist labels from docker daemon.